# ignore the rest of the code after a long loop

Tags: c, bigdata

I am working with big data using C programming language.

this my code

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int x , y;
    FILE *fp;
    if((fp = fopen("huge.in", "r+")) == NULL) {
        printf("No such file\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int c = 1;
    while(fscanf(fp,"%d %d",&x,&y) != EOF){
        printf("%d %d %d\n",x,y,c);
        c++;
    }

    printf("The number of edges:%d\n",c);
    return 0;
}
```

the problem when I try small file, the program print the the number of the edges at the end but when I try a huge file 15GB the program didn't print the value of c at the end.

update:

I tried the code without the print inside the loop. and it gave an error " Segmentation fault; core dumped"

Comment: Is the program returning 0 still?

Comment: how I can check that? it is finish without errors.

Comment: What is the last line printed in the failing case?

Comment: You say your program finishes with errors; what are the errors?

Comment: Of topic: I think I would change `while(fscanf(fp,"%d %d",&x,&y) != EOF){` to `while(fscanf(fp,"%d %d",&x,&y) == 2){` but it doesn't explain the problem

Comment: While we are off topic, instead of the `printf("No such file\n")`, `perror("huge.in")` would be better.  That will explain the actual problem (which could be caused by many things other than a missing file; permissions, for example) instead of potentially misleading the user.

Comment: at the end there is empty line.

Comment: @user1927468 that the small working file has the same format as the large file? I mean the empty line. Could you post the file (a minature of it)?

Comment: Your program looks fine, did you change *anything* from the code you are running before posting it?

Comment: It seems strange that you get a segmentation fault. In principle your code is unsafe as things like integer overflow and scan of integers higher than max int is undefined but I doubt that is the problem here. Have you checked the core dump, e.g. using gdb.